# error running endpoints command get-client-lib:

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

i have just finished updateding to Android Studio 1.3.2 (Stable), Gradle 2.4, Gradle App Engine Plugin to 1.9.24.

When i try to do a gradle sync, i get the error bellow. I searched for solutions but haven't found anything yet. I'm still learning the in's and out's. Thanks in advance.

This is the error:-

> :Backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs FAILED

Error:

```
 Execution failed for task ':Backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs'.
 There was an error running endpoints command get-client-lib:    
 com.example.mymodule.Backend.MyEndpoint
```

stacktrace:

```
E:\Android\Work-space\App>gradle Backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs --stacktrace
```

:Backend:appengineDownloadSdk

:Backend:compileJava UP-TO-DATE

:Backend:processResources UP-TO-DATE

:Backend:classes UP-TO-DATE

:Backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':Backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs'.

  > There was an error running endpoints command get-client-lib: com.example.mymodule.Backend.MyEndpoint
- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':Backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs'.
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:310)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
      at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
      at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
      at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
      at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
      at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
      at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
      at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
      at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
      at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
      at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
      at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:90)
      at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
      at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
      at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
      at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
      at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
      at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
      at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:40)
      at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:169)
      at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
      at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
      at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
      at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
      at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
      at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
      at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
      at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
      at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
      at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
      at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
      at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
      at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
  Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: There was an error running endpoints command get-client-lib: com.example.mymodule.Backend.MyEndpo
  int
      at com.google.appengine.task.endpoints.EndpointsTask.runEndpointsCommand(EndpointsTask.groovy:52)
      at com.google.appengine.task.endpoints.EndpointsTask$runEndpointsCommand.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.appengine.task.endpoints.GetClientLibsTask.executeTask(GetClientLibsTask.groovy:39)
      at com.google.appengine.task.AbstractTask.start(AbstractTask.groovy:39)
      at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTask
  Factory.java:226)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFa
  ctory.java:219)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFa
  ctory.java:208)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:589)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:572)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
      ... 46 more
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.mymodule.Backend.MyEndpoint
      at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.GenApiConfigAction.loadClasses(GenApiConfigAction.java:109)
      at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.GenApiConfigAction.genApiConfig(GenApiConfigAction.java:90)
      at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.GetClientLibAction.getClientLib(GetClientLibAction.java:78)
      at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.GetClientLibAction.execute(GetClientLibAction.java:57)
      at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.EndpointsTool.execute(EndpointsTool.java:69)
      at com.google.appengine.task.endpoints.EndpointsTask.runEndpointsCommand(EndpointsTask.groovy:49)
      ... 57 more

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 33.809 secs

Answer (score 2):

This problem was caused because i deleted the template generated cloud endpoints API, and i did not get a usage warning when deleting the files.

To solve this simply remove any references to the API deleted in the WEB.INF/web.xml folder.

That is if you have a web project included. After i updated Android Studio i get a usage warning when doing a safe delete.